# Adding items in the list without using reference object and setter methods

Tags: java, list, jsp, object, getter-setter

In order to display my data row-wise i.e first row then another row.I added data from ResultSet into list through reference object .Ex-

```
  while (rs.next()) {
                           Comp_Mps ref = new Comp_Mps();

                              ref.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));
                              ref.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));
                              ref.setBeam_energy(rs.getString(3));
                              ref.setst4_vs6_bag1_rb(rs.getString(4));

                          st_jsp.add(ref);

                        }
```

where

st_jsp is

```
List<Comp_Mps> st_jsp=new ArrayList<Comp_Mps>();
```

and Comp_Mps is class name.
In jsp I display the data as

```
{(r.beam_energy)}
```

But now I have a large database and I have around 200 columns.So I won't be able to create getter and setter methods for all the columns.So what other way exists to add data in list and display it through jsp page in proper format i.e. row-wise and moreover I have to subtract data in jsp,I'm not able to do it in java. Subtraction code in jsp is

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.st4_vs6_bag8_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag8_rb)}" 
 maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm">      </fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
```

Comment: If you have two hundred columns, both your tables and your Java objects are desperately in need of being split up. More than about 10 is a reliable indication.

Comment: that is I'm asking.How??